# Why does AngularJS resource return promise and resolved?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a super simple service that returns a JSON list:

```
angular.module('hostService', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Host', function($resource){
      return $resource('/api/v1/host', {}, {
        'query':   {method:'GET',  isArray : true},
      });
  });
```

When I call it:

```
$scope.hosts = Host.query(function(d) {
    console.log(d);
});
```

I receive

```
[Resource, Resource, Resource, Resource, Resource, Resource, Resource, Resource, $promise: Object, $resolved: true]
```

What is that nonsense at the end? I want to iterate through the items and do something:

```
$scope.hosts = Host.query(function(d) {
            for(i in $scope.hosts) {
                doSomething($scope.hosts[i]);
            }
        });
```

but now have to check that they are not the "promise" or "resolved".

Answer (score -1):

You are attempting to pass through the function as a parameter in the request.  '$resource' returns a promise you can use to iterate through the results when they are returned from the server:

*you'll need to inject `$log` to make the code below work*

```
Host.query().$promise.then(
  //success
  function(results) {
    $scope.hosts = results;
    results.forEach(results, function(val,key) { $log.info(key + ' : ' + val); });
  },
  //error
  function(err) {
    $log.error(err);
  }
);
```